# Quebrar linha quando os componentes dentro do RecyclerView ocuparem a largura total da tela

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

É possível fazer com que quando a largura dos componentes de uma lista ocuparem a largura total da tela, o próximo componente desça uma linha? Eu não quero utilizar o scroll, se não for possível fazer isso com o RecyclerView quais são os recursos que eu posso utilizar para resolver esse problema ?

**Obs.** Texto1, Texto2, Texto3, etc... São layouts que possuem um TextView e os textos dentro desses TextViews são de tamanhos variados.

[image: Quebrar linha quando componentes chegarem ao final da tela]

Answer (score 0):

Acho que você esta usando o LinearLayoutManager, basta você trocar para o GridLayoutManager.

Comment: Eu não tinha testado o GridLayoutManager, porém testei aqui agora e ele tem colunas fixas, você insere isso ao criar a instância. O que eu estou buscando é quase isso, porém a primeira linha pode ter, por exemplo 5 TextView e na segunda 2 e na terceira 3 e assim por diante. Depois de fazer uma breve pesquisa, vi também aqui que tem um método que permite especificar a quantidade de colunas em cada linha, porém exige que eu saiba o tamanho do TextView... Talvez eu faça essa implementação manual se não surgir nenhuma opção melhor. Porém essa ainda não é a resposta completa, estamos no caminho.